# React-bootstrap button animation will not work and button wont center

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a react-bootstrap component and the loading animation will not play.

Also, the button wont center. I can use `margin-left: 30px;` to move it closer to the center but I dont want that as a solution because on bigger screens it goes off center. For the positioning, I am using an imported CSS file.

```
import Spinner from 'react-bootstrap/Spinner';
import { ButtonToolbar } from "react-bootstrap";
import  Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'

class Button extends React.Component{

            ......rest of react component........

            return(
                <div>
                    <ButtonToolbar >
                    <Button variant="primary">
                        <Spinner
                        as="span"
                        animation="border"
                        size="sm"
                        role="status"
                        aria-hidden="true"
                        />
                        Loading
                    </Button>
                    </ButtonToolbar>
                </div>
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or what I am not doing at all? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can center align your bootstrap button by modifying its container, here the `<ButtonToolbar>`

Like so:

```
<ButtonToolbar className="text-center d-block">
                <Button variant="primary">
                    <Spinner
                    as="span"
                    animation="border"
                    size="sm"
                    role="status"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                    />
                    Loading
                </Button>
</ButtonToolbar>
```

For the spinner, do you have any React Error?

Comment: thank you that fixed the button problem.  Can i ask you where you looked up the className="text-center d-block"? i tried to search for a way edit it but found no documentation.  Also, for the spinner, i have no React Error.  It should say "loading" and the dots are supposed to be animated.  But instead nothing animates

Comment: I found the documentation here: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/button-group/ and it's likely working as https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/. For the spinner, I don't see any problem in your code vs doc https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/spinners/ no console error neither I guess? :/